# Can I mount NTFS flash drive on linux

Tags: rhel, mount, ntfs

Hi I'm using RHEL 6 an WIN 7. I have a flash drive of 16GB. To copy the files which are above 4GB size I changed it to NTFS(FAT32 is allowing only file size below 4GB). But now I am not able to use in my Linux machine. Can I mount it with out loosing data on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install ntfs-3g as said by @lgnacio.

```
# rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
```

And installing the epel repo. You can install ntfs-3g as

```
#yum install ntfs-3g
```

And mount the ntfs drive as .

```
#mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/<your partition> /mnt/<mount point>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `ntfs-3g` from [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) first.

Comment: The kernel actually supports NTFS too, but only in read-only mode. ntfs-3g supports read/write too. It may be worth pointing out that it might be a little slow (because it's fuse based), but on a USB flash drive you'll never notice.

Comment: `ntfs.ko` isn't built on a EL kernel.